# How to create a button in python that would allow me to drop a file on an html page

Tags: html

Being a beginner in code, I would like to know how we can create a button that would allow me to drop a file on an html page.
Tha,k you for your help

Answer (score 0):

according to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop) you should first define the dropping area in your page by html and then handle the dropped files by java script. You can use the following implementation:

Respectively in your .js, .css, and .html files:

```js
function dragOverHandler(ev) {
  console.log('File(s) in drop zone');

  // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function dropHandler(ev) {
  console.log('File(s) dropped');

  // Prevent default behavior (Prevent file from being opened)
  ev.preventDefault();

  if (ev.dataTransfer.items) {
    // Use DataTransferItemList interface to access the file(s)
    for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length; i++) {
      // If dropped items aren't files, reject them
      if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
        var file = ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile();
        console.log('... file[' + i + '].name = ' + file.name);
      }
    }
  } else {
    // Use DataTransfer interface to access the file(s)
    for (var i = 0; i < ev.dataTransfer.files.length; i++) {
      console.log('... file[' + i + '].name = ' + ev.dataTransfer.files[i].name);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
#drop_zone {
  border: 5px solid blue;
  width:  200px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="drop_zone" ondrop="dropHandler(event);" ondragover="dragOverHandler(event);">
  <p>Drag one or more files to this Drop Zone ...</p>
</div>
```